# Is it possible to retrieve all tables in a database with a query?

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssms

I would like to know if there is a query that show all the tables in a database (including the data in tables?

For example, if I wanted to show the results of an individual table I would simply write select * from [table]. However, is there a query that execute on the database to show the results of all tables in the database?

Comment: Do you mean something like `select * from *'? Never seen anything like that in any RDBMS

Comment: Hi @Quido, yes, something like that. I know its a strange question, but is it possible?

Comment: or just run `sp_msforeachtable 'select  * from ?'` directly as-is.

Comment: I think it would be hard to implement, since any select requires the same number of columns for all data rows. That would not be possible for mulitple tables. Not an expert in MS-SQL (assuming you mean that), but there is definitely nothing in ANSI-SQL for that.

Comment: You should use [Information schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_schema), [System Information Schema Views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/system-information-schema-views-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: `exec sp_msforeachtable 'select '''' as [?], * from ?';` This will return the table name as the first column name, with empty string as the value for every row in that column (so that you can see the table name even if there are no rows), and the data in the subsequent columns.

Comment: Hi @allmhuran, thanks for reaching out. Going to try this suggestion now..

Answer (score -3):

If you want to display the contents of all tables in a database, you would typically need to query each table individually. There isn't a single query that can display the contents of all tables in a database in one go, especially if the tables have different structures.

However, if you're using a database management system that supports dynamic SQL, you could write a script or stored procedure to generate and execute the necessary SELECT queries for each table.

Comment: [Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1)